# Why is my http.client request in Python returning [ValueError: No tables found]

Tags: python, api, http

I'm trying to use the http.client library to gain access to EPC data through the use of the API found here;

https://epc.opendatacommunities.org/docs/api/domestic

I cannot get the data in the correct format, I have managed to get a 'bytes' variable, which seems to be html, but cannot get it to a readable dataframe.

```
from http.client import HTTPSConnection
from base64 import b64encode
import pandas as pd

def basic_auth(username, password):
    token = b64encode(f"{username}:{password}".encode('utf-8')).decode("ascii")
    return f'Basic {token}'

username = "ethan.mercer@aecom.com"
password = "bc6b6b549004ec082a1b8a3a03bd9d1adde3f02b"

c = HTTPSConnection("epc.opendatacommunities.org")

headers = { 'Authorization' : basic_auth(username, password) }
c.request('GET', '/api/v1/domestic/search', headers=headers)

res = c.getresponse()

data = res.read() 
data = pd.read_html(data,skiprows=1)[0]
```

Output:`ValueError: No tables found`

**Updated code:**

```
import json
import requests
import pandas as pd
from base64 import b64encode

def basic_auth(username, password):
    token = b64encode(f"{username}:{password}".encode('utf-8')).decode("ascii")
    return f'Basic {token}'

username = "ethan.mercer@aecom.com"
password = "bc6b6b549004ec082a1b8a3a03bd9d1adde3f02b"

headers = {'Accept' : 'application/json', 'Authorization' : basic_auth(username, password) }
EPC_Data = requests.get('https://epc.opendatacommunities.org/api/v1/domestic/search?local-authority=E08000003', headers=headers).text
EPC_Data = json.loads(EPC_Data)
```

This code now works correctly, and is returning a dictionary of headers.

Comment: I don't see  a `<table>` tag inside the response

Answer (score 1):

Because your data is in bytes try decoded it like this

```py
data.decode("utf-8")
```

this should convert your data to an entire string. This is what you can give to pd.read_html (this only will work if there are `<table>` tags in it)